# Gnuplot - fitting

Tags: gnuplot, curve-fitting

What is the problem with fitting, please?

```
A = -100
C = -0.3
D = 22
f(x) = A*sin(2*pi*x+C)+D
fit f(x) 'RV_phase' via A,C,D
g(x) = -100*sin(2*pi*x-0.3)+22

plot 'RV_phase' u 3:2 with points pt 7 ps 1 notitle, f(x) lc rgb "black" title "Fitted", g(x) lc rgb "red" title "Manual setting"
```

Is manual set curve sufficiently?
[image]

Comment: You must also specify the data columns when fitting: `fit f(x) 'RV_phase' using 3:2 via A,C,D`

Comment: @Alex: My impression is that you are fitting radial velocity curves. Have a look to the [Fortran version](http://www.astro.physik.uni-goettingen.de/~zechmeister/gls.php) of the GLS periodogram. It contains a gnuplot script to fit circular and Keplerian orbits.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the fitting you must specify the same data columns with `using` like you use when plotting:

```
fit f(x) 'RV_phase' using 3:2 via A,C,D 
plot 'RV_phase' using 3:2 with points, f(x) with lines
```